# Bad length count when ng-minlength and ng-pattern are define in angularjs

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

When i define a ng-minlength and ng-pattern, this code doesn't work good :

```
<span class="myForm_textarea" ng-show="myFormZR.textarea.$dirty"><br /><br />characters : {{0 + myForm.textarea.length}} writed / 500 limit</span>
```

count is go to 0 when a string matche the regex or count is 0 until the minlength is reached. i made a plunkr for that : http://plnkr.co/edit/R6kGJmlQ4TgGf16kAmYi?p=preview

Comment: It's by design that the binding model will be set to undefined if it's invalid. To workaround that, I need to know first which version of angularjs you are using?

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK, there is no known workaround for the angular 1.3 yet. But it seems this feature is planned in 1.3 milestone, see [#8290](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8290). Your only option seems to be downgrade to use angular 1.2.x.

Comment: same issue with 1.2.21 ...

Comment: It doesn't work out of the box, but there is a workaround for 1.2.x. If you are going to use 1.2.21, I could provide you a workaround.

Comment: ok, i'm interesting in that, can you put in in the plunkr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angularjs 1.2.x, you could workaround the problem by writing a custom directive to restore the invalid value.

```
app.directive('allowInvalid', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    priority: 1, // force the postLink below to run after other directives
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
        return (viewValue === undefined) ? modelCtrl.$viewValue : viewValue;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

and put it in the textarea:

```
<textarea ng-model="myForm.textarea" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="500"  ng-pattern="textareaRegex" allow-invalid></textarea>
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/H0YePKFwkvaBZgnxCRMB?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little workaround that I started using for this specific problem within forms.

Instead of using `myForm.textarea.length` try using `myForm.textarea.$viewValue.length`. This way, validation is tracking your model and you still have an accurate way to keep track of your character count.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to limit the maximum characters in the textarea, you can use maxlength attribute (in addition to the ng-maxlength):

```
<textarea ng-maxlength="500"  maxlength="500" />
```

Comment: It's not the problem, i already now that. Problem is the bad length count with ng-minlength and ng-pattern.

Comment: actually that's the way angular validation works with ng-maxlength. If you want different behaviour, you can write your own maxlength directive

Comment: I do not understand how it can be a problem related to maxlength because when i don't use it, my problem is still present. Problem still present too with ng-pattern when minlength is not used.